# classification algorithms for anomaly detection when there is class imbalance

Tags: r, classification

My target variable is boolean and has 0.001% of NO records and remaining YES records.
Can anyone suggest algorithms which are best for anomaly detection in R when there is severe class imbalance.

Comment: What's an "anomaly" here? A "No" where you'd expect a "Yes" and vice-versa?

Comment: anomaly here is occurrence of "No" when you would expect "Yes" to happen

Comment: Anomaly detection algorithms are mostly *intended* to be used with an imbalanced data set. By definition, an anomaly is something unusual, and you typically don't train a discriminator, but some estimate of probability density for non-anomalies.

Comment: So you basically want to predict if it is a YES or a NO?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty detailed summary on [Handling Imbalanced Classes](http://www.svds.com/learning-imbalanced-classes/). Since you mentioned R, you might want to take a look at [`unbalanced`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/unbalanced/unbalanced.pdf) package.